# Large gaussian blur filter without revealing SVG border

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to create a kind of "spotlight" effect over a large background image where the user can use the cursor to view parts of an image.

I'm currently applying a gaussian blur `filter` to a `mask` element which is positioned at the cursor and reveals parts of the large `image`.

I would like to have a higher blur amount in order to get a softer edge, but when I increase the value of the `stdDeviation` attribute inside the filter, the border of the SVG is revealing – I have attached two images to illustrate, also you can see it in this pen https://codepen.io/moevbiz/pen/YbwErx

Here is my code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="50"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
      <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="100" ry="100" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></ellipse>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
</svg>

<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" alt="" />
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```
document.onmousemove=function(e) {
  var mousecoords = getMousePos(e);
  var mouseX = mousecoords.x;
  var mouseY = mousecoords.y;
  var ellipse = document.getElementById('ellipse');
  ellipse.setAttribute('cx', mouseX);
  ellipse.setAttribute('cy', mouseY)
};


function getMousePos(e) {
  return {x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY};
}
```

[image: current(i want to have a larger blur than this)]
current(i want to have a larger **blur** than this, not just increase the ellipse radius)

[image: increased blur value with visible borders]
increased blur value with visible borders

Thankful for any hints!

Comment: You can play around with the ellipse element, rx & ry?

Comment: this will only change the radius of the circle, the blur radius remains unaffected = border still visible…

Comment: Instead of applying the filter you may fill the ellipse with a radial gradient from white in the middle to black

Comment: pretty smart, sounds like it will work! gonna try and let you know ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to increase your [Filter Region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#filters-FilterEffectsRegion).

By default it is `<filter x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%">`.  But if you want to use a large blur, you will need to increase it, to cater for the way that the blur spreads the pixels out further.

Something like `<filter id="filter" x="-75%" y="-75%" width="250%" Height="250%">` works for your example.

https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/qGboxR